# How to expand a command for use as an argument in itself

Tags: macros

I've tried to get this macro to work for a couple days. I've simplified the problem down to this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xintgcd,xintfrac} % Simplify Script

\begin{document}

\newcommand*\simpFrac[2]
  {\begingroup
     \edef\gcd{\xintGCD{#1}{#2}}%
     \ifnum \xintNum{\xintDiv{#2}{\gcd}}=1
     \xintNum{\xintDiv{#1}{\gcd}}
     \else
     \frac{\xintNum{\xintDiv{#1}{\gcd}}}{\xintNum{\xintDiv{#2}{\gcd}}}%
     \fi
   \endgroup}

   \def\surgefif{\edef\simpFrac{4}{2}} 
   $\simpFrac{10}{ \surgefif }$

\end{document}
```

The `simpFrac` command is one mostly "copy and pasted", except that I added the ability for it to return an integer if the denominator is

I tried using `\edef`, messed around with `\expandafter`, I can't get anything to work, I give up.

Expected behaviour:

- Simplifies 4/2 -> 2
- Simplifies 10/2 -> 5

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: `\simpFrac` does assignments, so it cannot deliver the result in `\edef`.

Comment: What output would you expect if you use `\simpFrac{3}{2}` as `\surgefif`?

Comment: Undefined Behavior, I'm writing an assignment and I know ahead of time that \surgefif is always going to be an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with lualatex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcommand*\simpFrac[2]{%
  \directlua{
    if (#1/#2 - math.floor(#1/#2)) == 0 
      then tex.sprint(math.floor(#1/#2)) 
      else tex.sprint("#1/#2") 
    end}
}

\begin{document}

\simpFrac{10}{3}

\def\surgefif{\simpFrac{4}{2}} 
   
\simpFrac{10}{\surgefif}

\simpFrac{10}{\simpFrac{4}{2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was under the incorrect impression that LuaLatex was its own independent program to MikTex, and I'd have to set up a bunch of command line scripts. I have since realized otherwise. Thankyou for making me realize, I will use LUA in the future as well :)